# Enviar um ArrayList de objetos para uma Activity

Tags: java, android

Como enviar um ArrayList de objetos para uma activity no Android?

ex: Tenho uma ArrayList de objetos Livros, quero que quando clicar no botão este arrayList de objetos sejam passados para uma outra activity..

Comment: Você pode passar por extra no `Intent`, desde que os itens do `ArrayList` sejam `Parcelable` ou `Serializable`.

Comment: Oi Felipe! Poderia esclarecer um pouco mais a pergunta? Enviar a partir de onde? :)

Comment: enviar de uma Activity para outra.. Editei

Comment: @Wakim pesquisei sobre Parcelable, mas estou entendendo nada, tem como responder a pergunta com um exemplo? Não estou entendendo como implementa o Parcelable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Existem três formas simples de passar um `ArrayList` como parâmetro para uma `Activity`.

1. Métodos estáticos:

   **Na `ActivityA`**

   ```
   // Dados a serem passados
   ArrayList<Tipo> dados = ...;

   Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);

   // Seta num campo estático da ActivityB
   ActivityB.dados = dados;

   startActivity(i);
   ```

   **Na `ActivityB`**

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // Recupera os parâmetros passados pelo atributo estatico
       ArrayList<Tipo> dados = ActivityB.dados;

       // Limpar para nao ocorrer Leak
       ActivityB.dados = null;
   }
   ```

   Essa forma não é boa, porque força um **Acoplamento** entre as `Activities`, o que não é uma boa prática, mas ela existe.
2. Usando a interface `java.lang.Serializable`:

   **Na `ActivityA`**

   ```
   // Dados a serem passados
   ArrayList<Tipo> dados = ...;

   Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);

   // Seta num campo estático da ActivityB
   i.putSerializableExtra("dados", dados);

   startActivity(i);
   ```

   **Classe Tipo**

   ```
   public class Tipo implements Serializable {
       // Declaracao da sua classe
   }
   ```

   **Na `ActivityB`**

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // Recupera os parâmetros passados pelo atributo estatico
       ArrayList<Tipo> dados = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("dados");
   }
   ```

   A classe `ArrayList` implementa a interface `Serializable` mas, para funcionar, o item que parametriza o `ArrayList` também precisa implementar `Serializable`.
3. Usando a interface `Parcelable`:

   **Na `ActivityA`**

   ```
   // Dados a serem passados
   ArrayList<Tipo> dados = ...;

   Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);

   // Seta num campo estático da ActivityB
   i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("dados", dados);

   startActivity(i);
   ```

   **Classe Tipo**

   ```
   public class Tipo implements Parcelable {
       // Declaracao da sua classe

       public Tipo(Parcel in) {
           // Esse construtor apesar de nao ser requerido pela interface,
           // e necessario por causa do protocolo implicito do Parcelable
           // Lembrar da ordem que foi escrita no writeToParcel!!
           seuCampoInt = in.readInt();
           seuCampoString = in.readString();
           // Demais campos
       }

       @Override
       public int describeContents() {
           return 0;
       }

       @Override
       public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
           // Serializa os campos da sua classe,
           // lembrando que essa ordem e importante no construtor
           dest.writeInt(...);
           dest.writeString(...);
       }

       // Como parte do contrato implicito,
       // sua classe precisa de um atributo estatico chamado "CREATOR"

       public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
           public Tipo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
               return new Tipo(in);
           }

           public Tipo[] newArray(int size) {
               return new Tipo[size];
           }
       };
   }
   ```

   **Na `ActivityB`**

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // Recupera os parâmetros passados pelo atributo estatico
       ArrayList<Tipo> dados = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("dados");
   }
   ```

Na minha opinião, o melhor é usando a interface `Parcelable`, por ser comprovadamente mais rápido<sup>1</sup>.

Qualquer dúvida sobre o `Parcelable`, de uma olhada na documentação da [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) e [`Parcelable.Creator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.Creator.html) e [`Parcel`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html).

Referências:

1. http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente