# Problemas ao enviar dados de um ListView para outra Activity

Tags: java, android, web-service, listview

PerguntaAdapter

public class PerguntaAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

```
private List<Pergunta> lista;
private Context context;

public PerguntaAdapter(Context context, List<Pergunta> lista){
    this.context = context;
    this.lista = lista;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return lista.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return lista.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

static class ViewHolder{
     TextView tvPergunta;
     Button btnSim, btnNao, btnEnviarRespostas;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    try{
        Pergunta pergunta = lista.get(position);

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.modelo_questionario, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.btnSim.setOnClickListener(this);
            viewHolder.btnNao.setOnClickListener(this);

            viewHolder.tvPergunta = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textPerguntas);
            viewHolder.btnSim = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnSim);
            viewHolder.btnNao = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnNao);

        }
        else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        //convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.btnSim.setTag(R.layout.modelo_questionario, position);
        viewHolder.btnNao.setTag(R.layout.modelo_questionario, position);

        viewHolder.tvPergunta.setText(pergunta.getPergunta());



    }catch(Exception erro){
        Log.e("Erro", "Erro: "+erro.getStackTrace());
    }

    return convertView;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // Com essa posicao eh possivel saber qual pergunta ele respondeu

    int position = (Integer) v.getTag(R.layout.modelo_questionario);

    Pergunta pergunta = lista.get(position);

    // Comparo o ID da View que foi clicada com o ID do botao SIM,
    // gerando um booleano

    boolean resposta = v.getId() == R.id.btnSim;

    // Criar um campo na pergunta para armazenar a resposta
    // Ou usar um ArrayList ou SparseArray para armezar.

    pergunta.setResposta(resposta);
}

public List<Pergunta> getPerguntas() {
    return lista;
}
```

Activity do questionário

public class Activity_Questionario extends Activity {

```
Funcoes funcoes = new Funcoes();
String[] perguntas;
String[] id;
int posicao = 0;
int posicao2 = 0;
Activity_Login l;
public String resposta2;
public String idQues;

public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_questionario);

    l = new Activity_Login();



    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Log.i("Logar", "Entrou no evento");
    String url = "http://"+l.ip+"/projetotcc/android/questionario.php";

    String respostaRetornada = null;

    Log.i("Logar", "Vai entrar no try");

    try{
        respostaRetornada = ConexaoHttpClient.executaHttpGet(url);
        String resposta = respostaRetornada.toString();
        resposta = resposta.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        Log.i("Perguntas", "Perguntas: "+resposta);


        char separador = '#';
        int contaPerguntas = 0;

        for (int i=0; i < resposta.length(); i++){
            if (separador == resposta.charAt(i)){
                contaPerguntas++;
                perguntas = new String[contaPerguntas];
            }
        }

        char caracterLido = resposta.charAt(0);
        String pergunta = "";

        for (int i=0; caracterLido != '^'; i++){
            caracterLido = resposta.charAt(i);
            Log.i("Chars", "Chars das perguntas"+caracterLido);

            if (caracterLido != '#'){

                //pergunta+= (char) caracterLido;
                if (caracterLido == '*'){
                    pergunta = pergunta + " ";
                }else
                    pergunta = pergunta + caracterLido;
            }else{
                Log.i("Nome", "Nome: "+pergunta);
                perguntas[posicao] =""+ pergunta;
                Log.i("Nome posição ["+posicao+"]", ""+perguntas[posicao]);
                posicao = posicao + 1;
                pergunta = "";
            }
        }
        Log.i("Fim", "Fim do for");

    }catch(Exception erro){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Erro: "+erro, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("Erro", "Erro: "+erro.getStackTrace());
    }

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvPre);

    List<Pergunta> perguntasList = new ArrayList<Pergunta>();
    Pergunta p = new Pergunta();

    for (final String k : perguntas) {
        p = new Pergunta();
        p.setPergunta(k);
        perguntasList.add(p);
    }
    lv.setAdapter(new PerguntaAdapter(this, perguntasList));

    PerguntaAdapter adapter = (PerguntaAdapter) lv.getAdapter();
    List<Pergunta> ListaPergunta = adapter.getPerguntas();

    ArrayList<Boolean> respostas = new ArrayList<Boolean>(ListaPergunta.size());

    for(Pergunta pergunta : ListaPergunta) {
        respostas.add(pergunta.getResposta());
    }

    Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity_Conf_Inicio_Ques.class);

    i.putExtra("RESPOSTAS", respostas);

    startActivity(i);

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


            String url3 = "http://"+l.ip+"/projetotcc/android/parametroQuestionario.php";
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> parametrosPost3 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            parametrosPost3.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pq", Pq));

            String respostaRetornada3 = null;

            Log.i("Logar", "Vai entrar no try");

            try{
                respostaRetornada3 = ConexaoHttpClient.executaHttpPost(url3, parametrosPost3);
                idQues = respostaRetornada3.toString();
                idQues = idQues.replaceAll(" ", "*");
                idQues = idQues.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                Log.i("Pacientes", "Id do questionario: "+idQues);

            }catch(Exception erro){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Erro: "+erro, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }



    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    PerguntaAdapter pr = new PerguntaAdapter(this, perguntasList);

    String urlInserirPacRes = "http://"+l.ip+"/projetotcc/android/inserirPacRes.php";
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> parametrosPost2 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    parametrosPost2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", resposta2));


}
```

}

Confirmação dos questionários

public class Activity_Conf_Inicio_Ques extends Activity {

```
Button btnConfirma, btnCancela;
EditText editConfirm;
AutoCompleteTextView acPacientes2;
String[] pacientes;
String[] pacientes2;
int posicao = 0;
int posicao2 = 0;
public static int senhaDigitada2;
Activity_Login l;

public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_conf_inicio_ques);

    l = new Activity_Login();

    ArrayList<Boolean> respostas = (ArrayList<Boolean>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("RESPOSTAS");

    Log.i("Logar", "Entrou no evento");
    String url = "http://"+l.ip+"/projetotcc/android/listarPacientes.php";

    String respostaRetornada = null;

    Log.i("Logar", "Vai entrar no try");

    try{
        respostaRetornada = ConexaoHttpClient.executaHttpGet(url);
        String resposta = respostaRetornada.toString();
        resposta = resposta.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        Log.i("Pacientes", "Pacientes: "+resposta);         

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        char separador  = '#';
        int contaPacientes = 0;

        for (int i=0; i < resposta.length(); i++){
            if (separador == resposta.charAt(i)){
                contaPacientes++;
                pacientes  = new String[contaPacientes];
            }
        }

        char caracterLido = resposta.charAt(0);
        String nome  = "";

        for (int i=0; caracterLido != '^'; i++){
            caracterLido = resposta.charAt(i);
            Log.i("Chars", "Chars do paciente"+caracterLido);

            if (caracterLido != '#'){
                nome+= (char) caracterLido;
            }else{
                Log.i("Nome", "Nome: "+nome);
                pacientes[posicao] =""+ nome;
                Log.i("Nome posição ["+posicao+"]", ""+pacientes[posicao]);
                posicao = posicao + 1;
                nome = "";
            }
        }

    }catch(Exception erro){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Erro: "+erro, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, pacientes);
    acPacientes2 = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.acPacientes2);
    acPacientes2.setAdapter(adapter);


    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    final Intent intent2 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity_Questionario.class);
    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    final int Senha = intent.getIntExtra("senha", 0);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Senha: "+Senha, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    editConfirm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSenhaConfirm);

    btnConfirma = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConfirmarQues);
    btnConfirma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String senhaDigitada = editConfirm.getText().toString();
            if (!(senhaDigitada.length() == 0)){
                senhaDigitada2 = Integer.parseInt(senhaDigitada);
                Log.v("???", "Valor = " + senhaDigitada2);

                if (senhaDigitada2 == Senha){
                    intent2.putExtra("paciente", acPacientes2.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent2);
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Senha incorreta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }   
        }
    });

    btnCancela = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancelarQues);
    btnCancela.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cancelaQues();

        }
    });
}

public void cancelaQues(){
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Emerson, você pode enviar dados de uma `Activity` para outra de duas formas: variáveis estáticas (ruim) e `Itent` `Extras` (boa). Dê uma olhada na minha resposta para essa pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27175/enviar-um-arraylist-de-objetos-para-uma-activity/27195#27195 que pode te ajudar a começar. Seria bom você começar com algum código e caso tenha alguma dúvida, editar essa pergunta e incluir o código que não funciona.

Comment: Então Wakim, o problema é que quando eu eu faço dessa maneira, de mandar com o Intent Extras, ele acaba mandando apenas da primeira posição...
Precisava de um exemplo de como mandar de todas as posições do listview, pq as respostam são diferentes...
Abraçç...

Comment: Emerson, como você esta construindo seu `ListView`? Coloque seu código para ficar mais palpável.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ainda falta bastante coisa para ser feito nesse `Adapter`. Vou tentar fazer um esboço geral na solução.

Os pontos que abordarei:

1. Falta armazenar no `Adapter` qual a resposta para cada pergunta, usando o `OnClickListener` nos botões, como chegou a fazer.
2. Na `Activity` você precisa consultar o `Adapter` pelas respostas.
3. Enviar o `ArrayList` com as respostas como `Intent Extra` para a outra `Activity`.

**Adapter**

```
// O próprio Adapter é o ClickListener das views, pode mudar isso, mas fiz dessa forma por simplicidade e reducao do numero de objetos criados.
public Adapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Codigo que popula a view

        viewHolder.btnSim.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewHolder.btnNao.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Guardo na View, a posicao da lista ao qual ela se refere.
        // Sera usado depois para saber qual pergunta ele respondeu
        // A tag precisa ser um valor autogerado e unico para nao ter conflito.
        viewHolder.btnSim.setTag(R.layout.modelo_questionario, position);
        viewHolder.btnNao.setTag(R.layout.modelo_questionario, position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Com essa posicao eh possivel saber qual pergunta ele respondeu
        int position = (Integer) v.getTag(R.layout.modelo_questionario);

        Pergunta pergunta = lista.get(position);

        // Comparo o ID da View que foi clicada com o ID do botao SIM,
        // gerando um booleano
        boolean resposta = v.getId() == R.id.btnSim;

        // Criar um campo na pergunta para armazenar a resposta
        // Ou usar um ArrayList ou SparseArray para armezar.
        pergunta.setResposta(resposta);
    }
}
```

**Em sua Activity**

```
// Considerando que o Adapter ja tem as respostas armazenas nas perguntas
List<Pergunta> perguntas = adapter.getPerguntas();

ArrayList<Boolean> respostas = new ArrayList<Boolean>(perguntas.size());

for(Pergunta pergunta : perguntas) {
    respostas.add(pergunta.getResposta());
}

Intent i = new Intent(this, NovaActivity.class);

i.putExtra("RESPOSTAS", respostas);

startActivity(i);
```

**Na `NovaActivity`**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Restante do codigo...

    ArrayList<Boolean> respostas = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("RESPOSTAS");

    // Usar o array
}
```

É claro que você pode passar todas as perguntas, mas ai terá que ver em minha resposta [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27175/enviar-um-arraylist-de-objetos-para-uma-activity/27195#27195) como fazer isso. Seja através da interface `Serializable` ou `Parcelable`.

**Edit:**

Para pegar a lista de `Pergunta` precisa primeiro pegar a instância do `Adapter` e depois pegar a lista através dele.

```
PerguntaAdapter adapter = (PerguntaAdapter) lv.getAdapter();

// Criar o metodo getPerguntas para retornar a lista
List<Pergunta> perguntas = adapter.getPerguntas();
```

Comment: Pessoal, a discussão nos comentários estava se estendendo demais, então [movi para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17289/discussion-on-answer-by-wakim-problemas-ao-enviar-dados-de-um-listview-para-outr) ok? Vocês podem prosseguir por lá. Obrigado.

Comment: Ah, obrigado @bfavaretto, eu até tentei mas ele não tinha reputação suficiente :/