# Como passar dados de uma Activity para outra

Tags: android, listview

Estou criando um app para pizzarias na minha cidade e gostaria de saber se é possível enviar dados de uma *ListActivity* que contem nome de pizzas para uma outra *ListActivity* nomeada favoritos,
para que possa ser adicionada pizzas na lista de favoritos.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: A edição foi feita errada. Pois foi retirada a parte essencial onde eu falava que é de uma listview para outra, porém em activitys diferentes.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27175/enviar-um-arraylist-de-objetos-para-uma-activity

Comment: Rony, se não concordar com alguma edição feita na sua pergunta você pode reverte-la. Clique na palavra `editada`, que se encontra por cima da *"flair*" de quem editou. Depois, junto ao número da versão para a qual quer voltar, clique em `reverter`. Sugiro que leia a secção [como perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e compreenderá porque é que a edição foi feita.

Answer (score 2):

Existem algumas formas de "conversar" entre Activities, para simplesmente enviar algumas informações a outra activity, você pode usar o Bundle, desta forma:

```
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("nomeCliente", cliente.getNome(position));
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MinhaOutraActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Agora, se você precisa criar um sistema de favoritos, é preciso guardar estas informações no Banco de Dados ou em arquivo de preferência. Você pode consultar como fazer isso por aqui:

[How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

[SQLite no Android, Entendendo e Utilizando](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQ-Ir8pwxWA)

Comment: Opa gostei muito da resposta, esse código é colocado dentro da activity (pizzas) que irei passar para a outra correto? Tenho vários itens na lista, gostaria de que quando o usuário segurasse o item da listview aparecesse uma opção para adicionar uma pizza escolhida para a outra activity, posso fazer utilizando este código?

Answer (score 1):

Apenas uma correção é **putExtra** como abaixo:

```
     Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("nomeCliente", cliente.getNome(position));
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MinhaOutraActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Opa gostei muito da resposta, esse código é colocado dentro da activity (pizzas) que irei passar para a outra correto? Tenho vários itens na lista, gostaria de que quando o usuário segurasse o item da listview aparecesse uma opção para adicionar uma pizza escolhida para a outra activity, posso fazer utilizando este código?

Comment: É necessário mesmo criar um banco de dados?