# Como recuperar o id de um produto clicando no listview abrindo outra activity

Tags: android, listview

Estou fazendo uma aplicação para consulta de produtos utilizando um WebService.

Faço uma pesquisa no WS e trago as informações dos produtos que eu preciso. Depois, passo essas informações para um `Adapter` criar um `ListView` e logo em seugida passo esse `Adapter` na `Activity` onde mostro os produtos cadastrados.

Minha dúvida é: como eu faço para que quando seja clicado no produto eu abra os detalhes dele em uma outra `Activity`? Preciso passar por parâmetro a PK do produto para carregar os detalhes daquele produto.

Já tentei os códigos abaixo:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position, long id) {    
    int posicao = resultado.getSelectedItemPosition();
    intent  = new Intent(this, MostrarItemSelActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("codigo",posicao);
    startActivity(intent);
    this.finish();
}
```

Porém, dessa maneira, recupero a posição do item que eu cliquei dentro do `ListView` não consigo pegar as informações dentro dentro desse item como código, valor, descrição etc.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Poderia mostrar como você monta este `Adapter`?

Answer (score 0):

Existem algumas formas de "conversar" entre Activities, para simplesmente enviar algumas informações a outra activity, você pode usar o Bundle.

Creio que isso seja respondido nessa [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48745/como-passar-dados-de-uma-activity-para-outra)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. essa resposta também usa o Parcelable.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não entendi muito bem a pergunta, mas antes de mais nada eu te aconselho fortemente a usar um RecyclerView ao invés de um ListView.
https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=fr

Você possui um ArrayList de objetos Produto e você passou ele como parâmetro do Adapter do ListView, logo, basta você, dentro da função onItemClick, fazer algo do tipo: `Produto produto = resultado.get(position)`, considerando que resultado é um ArrayList contendo instancias de Produto.
O intent vai mudar um pouco, porque agora você precisa passar um objeto como parâmetro, aconselho uma leitura em: https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Mais no get(position) eu não pego a posição do objeto no Adapter? Não existe algo tipo 'Produto produto= resultado.get(position).get(atributo)'. Melhor explicando é o objeto produto na posição 0 e desse objeto  eu preciso apenas do codigo dele. ou algo parecido com isso kkkk. Bom de qualquer forma vou dar uma lida no link que vc deixou ali.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) ou [Serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html).

Exemplo Parcelable

```
package com.helpme.app;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Produto implements Parcelable {

 int codigo;
 String nome;

 public Produto(int codigo, String nome){
     this.codigo = codigo;
     this.nome = nome;
 }

 public int getCodigo() {
     return codigo;
 }

 public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
     this.codigo = codigo;
 }

 public String getNome() {
     return nome;
 }

 public void setNome(String nome) {
     this.nome = nome;
 }

 // PARCELABLE
 protected Produto(Parcel in) {
     setCodigo(in.readInt());
     setNome(in.readString());
 }

 public static final Creator<Produto> CREATOR = new Creator<Produto>() {
     @Override
     public Produto createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
         return new Produto(in);
     }

     @Override
     public Produto[] newArray(int size) {
         return new Produto[size];
     }
 };

 @Override
 public int describeContents() {
     return 0;
 }

 @Override
 public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
     dest.writeInt(getCodigo());
     dest.writeString(getNome());
 }
}
```

Passando os dados via Intent

```
Produto produto = new Produto(1, "SmartPhone");
Intent it = new Intent(this, MostrarItemSelActivity.class);
it.putExtra("produto", produto);
startActivity(it);
```

Recebendo os dados (tela "MostrarItemSelActivity")

```
Produto produto = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("produto");
```

Exemplo Serializable

```
package com.helpme.app;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Produto implements Serializable {

  int codigo;
  String nome;

  public Produto(int codigo, String nome){
      this.codigo = codigo;
      this.nome = nome;
  }

  public int getCodigo() {
      return codigo;
  }

  public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
      this.codigo = codigo;
  }

  public String getNome() {
      return nome;
  }

  public void setNome(String nome) {
      this.nome = nome;
  }
}

ArrayList<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<>();
produtos.add(new Produto(1, "SmartPhone"));
produtos.add(new Produto(2, "TV 42"));

Intent it = new Intent(this, MostrarItemSelActivity.class);
// Se quiser passar a lista inteira
it.putExtra("produtos", produtos); 
// Se quiser passar apenas um objeto
it.putExtra("produto", produtos.get(0)); 
startActivity(it);
```

Recuperando os dados

```
Produto produto = (Produto) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("produto");

ArrayList<Produto> produtos = (ArrayList<Produto>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("produtos");

System.out.println("Produto: "+ produto.getNome());
System.out.println("Produtos: "+ produtos.get(0).getNome());
```

Eu aconselho você a usar [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) no lugar do ListView

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.Vou implementar e posto aqui os resultados.