# Dados via Query String de Webview pra Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, webview

não sou grande entendedor de programação android. O que faço é com base em algo javascript que sei, que também não é muito. Então queria a ajuda de vocês. Tenho um aplicativo que roda em webview, na mainActivity. Mas preciso mandar uma informação para outra página que fica em outra activity. Só que essa informação é uma variável.

Por enquanto o código está assim. Na mainActivity tenho esse trecho, que interpreta que quando eu clicar no link pra página compartilhar.html, vai para a outra activity, no caso, CompartilhaActivity:

```
if (url.startsWith("compartilhar.html")) {
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CompartilhaActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
 return true;
 }
```

Só que só consigo abrir a página compartilhar.html na CompartilhaActivity assim:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(client);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/compartilhar.html");
```

Ou seja, estou informando ao código a página que quero abrir. Mas eu precisava que essa informação viesse de modo dinâmico.
Simplificando, na mainActivity, eu precisaria de algo como:

```
if (url.startsWith("compartilhar.html?id=58")) {
```

Lembrando que esse valor da id, viria do link via html, e seria uma variável.

E na compartilhaActivity preciso do caminho inverso, dizer ao html qual a variável que veio pela activity.

Na verdade não sei é possível isso. Por isso preciso de ajuda.
Desde já obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Voce pode usar essa post como ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48745/como-passar-dados-de-uma-activity-para-outra

Comment: Fiz alguns testes mas não consegui. Na verdade deu foi alguns erros...