# Problema ao passar ArrayList para outra Activity

Tags: android, listview, parâmetros, android-activity

Boa noite, estou com problemas para passar uma ListView de uma Activity para outra. O código da Activity que passa para a outra é o seguinte, chamada FiltrarImoveis.class:

```
       for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        Imovel imv = new Imovel();

                        JSONObject child = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String finalidade=child.getString("finalidadeImovel");

                        String tipo = child.getString("tipoImovel");

                        String genero = child.getString("generoImovel");

                        String descricao = child.getString("descricaoImovel");

                        String responsavel = child.getString("responsavelImovel");

                        String telefoneResponsavel = child.getString("telefoneResponsavel");

                        String situacaoImovel = child.getString("situacaoImovel");

                        String valor = child.getString("valor");
                        imv.setFinalidade(finalidade);
                        imv.setTipo(tipo);
                        imv.setGenero(genero);
                        imv.setDescricao(descricao);
                        imv.setResponsavel(responsavel);
                        imv.setTelefoneResponsavel(telefoneResponsavel);
                        imv.setSituacao(situacaoImovel);
                        imv.setValor(valor);

                        listaImovel.add(imv);
                    }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //showParsedJSON.setText(output);
            carregar(listaImovel);

        }
    }
}

public void carregar(ArrayList<Imovel> listaImovel){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,DetalhesImoveis.class);
    intent.putExtra("lista",listaImovel);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

A classe que herda a ListView é a seguinte, chamada DetalhesImoveis.class:

```
private ListView lvImoveis;
ArrayList<Imovel> listaImoveis;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalhes_imoveis);

    listaImoveis = (ArrayList<Imovel>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("lista");
    lvImoveis = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvImoveis);

    try {
        ArrayAdapter<Imovel> adpImovel = new ArrayAdapter<Imovel>(DetalhesImoveis.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaImoveis);

        lvImoveis.setAdapter(adpImovel);
        //Log.v("LISTAiMOVEIS", "ELEMENTOS DA LISTA: " +listaImoveis.get(0).getDescricao().toString() );
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.v("logs","ERROR CAUSED BY THE EXCEPTION LIST: "+e.toString());
    }

}
```

O problema é que não aparece nada na ListView, porém não entra na exceção, parecendo que a lista está chegando vazia.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Enviar um ArrayList de objetos para uma Activity](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27175/enviar-um-arraylist-de-objetos-para-uma-activity)

Comment: Descrobri, o erro era no WebService.